# android ImageView in RecyclerView loads the same image in random positions

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The RecyclerView I am using has an imageView with background as emptyheart image initially.When touched it should change to filledheart image.I add those checked positions to ArrayList using getAdapterPosition() of RecyclerViewAdapter and similarly remove it if the arraylist contains the touched position.but when I scroll it ImageView's background get changed at random positions.

RecyclerAdapter:

```
public class ShopOfferRecycAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShopOfferRecycAdapter.ShopOfferHolder> {
    View view;int counter=0;ArrayList checkeditems;
    @Override
    public ShopOfferHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shop_offers_recycler_adapter,parent,false);
        return new ShopOfferHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ShopOfferHolder holder, int position) {
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.mobile)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.mobile).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.mobile).cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("http://dress-trends.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Fashion-clothing-for-men-spring-summer-2016-61.jpg",holder.imageView,options);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    public class ShopOfferHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView,fav;
        public ShopOfferHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            checkeditems=new ArrayList();
            imageView=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_img);
            fav=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fav);
            fav.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       if(checkeditems.size()>0&&checkeditems.contains(getAdapterPosition()+1)==true) {
                        checkeditems.remove(getAdapterPosition()+1);
                        fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartnofill);
                        Log.e("Position removed", Integer.toString(getAdapterPosition()+1));
                    }
                        else if(checkeditems.contains(getAdapterPosition())==false){
                        fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartfill);
                        checkeditems.add(getAdapterPosition()+1);
                        Log.e("Pos added",Integer.toString(getAdapterPosition()+1));
//                        if(checkeditems.contains(getAdapterPosition()){
//                            checkeditems.remove(getAdapterPosition());
//                            Log.e("Position removed",Integer.toString(getAdapterPosition()));
                        }
                            return false;

                }

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `onBindViewHolder` where you're loading the image into `ImageView` use `holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(null)` like this. This will reset the ImageView and flush previously used Image immediately.

```
holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("http://dress-trends.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Fashion-clothing-for-men-spring-summer-2016-61.jpg",holder.imageView,options);
```

Comment: It is the imageview with variable 'fav' that has the problem mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your onBindViewHolder method

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

As you can understand by the name of the method, This will tell your recycler view to stop recycling your view holder.

> This can cause performance issues in some cases

But looking at the getCount method in your above code snippet it seems you have less elements to deal with :)